# how to print list item and index with max number in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in python, working on some code, this is the code I have so far and I don't know how to do it on here. so far I made a code about input the students' score from the user and print pass or retake. and now I am trying to print the highest Korean score with the name and index. and I want to know is there any way to print the name who got the highest score with index(ex. if Kira got the highest score than should be printed like: '3: Kira got the highest score on the Korean test.') How can I make this work? I searched up the internet and tried several ways but still doesn't work so I ask here..

```
students = ['Anna', 'Elsa', 'Kira']
korean = []
math = []

for i, name in enumerate(students,1):
    print('{}: {}'.format(i, name))

for stu in students:
    for y in range(1):
        kscore = int(input("Enter {}'s korean score: ".format(stu)))
    for x in range(1):
        mscore = int(input("Enter {}'s math score: ".format(stu)))
    if kscore <= 50 and mscore <= 70:
        print("You need to retake both")
    elif kscore <= 50:
        print("You need to retake Korean")
    elif mscore <= 70:
        print("You need to retake Math")
    else:
        print("You are pass")
    korean.append(kscore)
    math.append(mscore)

print('{}: {} got the highest score on the Korean test.'.format(i, name, max(korean)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to get the index of the maximum score take that index to get the person's name.
Here is the full code:
P.S: I changed some things because they were not efficient.

```
students = ['Anna', 'Elsa', 'Kira']
korean = []
math = []

for i, name in enumerate(students, 1):
    print('{}: {}'.format(i, name))

for stu in students:
    kscore = int(input("Enter {}'s korean score: ".format(stu)))
    mscore = int(input("Enter {}'s math score: ".format(stu)))
    if kscore <= 50 and mscore <= 70:
        print("You need to retake both")
    elif kscore <= 50:
        print("You need to retake Korean")
    elif mscore <= 70:
        print("You need to retake Math")
    else:
        print("You are pass")
    korean.append(kscore)
    math.append(mscore)

person = students[korean.index(max(korean))]

print('{}: {} got the highest score on the Korean test.'.format(i, person))
```